# Open a file directly in Teams from a tab

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, web-parts, microsoft-teams, spfx

I have deployed a SharePoint webpart (SharePoint Framework) to Microsoft Teams. In this web part, I have a list of files that I want to open directly in Teams.

I have tried to get the link from the "Files" tab (https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/7FFA7D9D-CBF1-4679-9C80-76446AE11ABD?tenantId=0f48c6f4-52a5-4553-b476-4ee2ee0aecca&fileType=docx&objectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fxyz.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FAZRTZ%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FArchitecture%2FTest.docx&baseUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fxyz.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FAZRTZ&serviceName=teams&threadId=19:0d1f6f397c51421189e791a9ab436a48@thread.skype&groupId=98edc5a8-02ac-4f58-8638-ea88ac6aaa4d) and put it in the href="" of the link. It does not work, it opens the file in the browser.

I also tried to put the direct link in the href (https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/AZRTZ/Shared Documents/General/Architecture/Test.docx). It downloads a copy of the file in the browser.

I want to open the file directly into Teams, the same way the files are opened if the user goes to the "Files" tab (eg. if the user opens a .doc file, Word Online in Teams must open, if the user opens an image, a previsualisation in Teams must be opened, ...)

[image: Teams WebPart Tab]

[image: Teams Files Tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Deep link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links) I managed to open the file directly in Teams. I had to format the URL :

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/{file-id}
?tenantId={tenant-id}
&fileType={file-type (jpg, xlsx, docx, ...)}
&objectUrl={file-encoded-link (SharePoint link, aboslute URL)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Succeed with a shorter version of the Deep Link syntax myself, in a message card from an incoming webhook connector, provided I used the [OpenUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#openuri-action) action syntax and not a plain markdown link:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/?fileType=<extension>&objectUrl=<absoluteUrl>
```

this was linking to Sharepoint files.