# Is it possible to deep link to a folder in the Files tab inside a channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to deep link my user to inside a specific folder inside a Channel's Files tab, but I can't see if this is possible. I've seen [this GH post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1174) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774236/open-a-file-directly-in-teams-from-a-tab), but neither is working for a folder, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to deeplink to a folder in files tab inside a channel.

Comment: ok, thanks for confirming. Any roadmap around it by any chance?

Comment: No, currently we don't have any roadmap as such. If you would like to have this feature, please raise a user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)

Comment: @Manish-MSFT Is this still the case as of today?